# Giving error while generating pdf

Tags: php, symfony

I am developing a website in symfony framework. I have generate pdf successfully using `SpraedPDFGeneratorBundle`. In My localhost everything working fine. When i check this on server I got error.

The exit status code '127' says something went wrong:

```
stderr: "sh: java: command not found"
stdout: ""
command: java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar "/home/bwcmm/public_html/PS/drp/vendor/spraed/pdf-generator-bundle/Spraed/PDFGeneratorBundle/Resources/java/spraed-pdf-generator.jar" --html "/tmp/tmp558d2d71e4d98." --pdf "/tmp/output558d2d71e3a1a.pdf" --encoding UTF-8.
```

Comment: `"sh: java: command not found"` I don't think you get anything that is more clear than this error message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your environment variable "java" is set.
The error suggests, that java cannot be found.

To check if java is installed type `java --version`
in your command line interface.